# Type an Array with a Union type in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, union-types

I'd like to use this array with a union type, but TS rightly assumes that its type is string:
"Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a" | "b"'."

```
function doSomething(value: "a" | "b"){}

["a", "b"].map(e => doSomething(e));
```

Is there a ways in which I can define the types of the array elements? If not, is there another way to solve this problem? I do not want to cast it in map().

Comment: You could use [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the compiler to infer a more specific type for `["a", "b"]`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRRdnw).  Does that meet your needs or is there some issue with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is using a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
function doSomething(value: "a" | "b"){}

(["a", "b"] as const).map(e => doSomething(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define the union type and add a type assertion, you can limit the type of that array to only accept union members.

```
type AorB = 'a' | 'b';
const testArray: AorB[] = ['a', 'b'];

function doSomething(value: AorB) {...};


const test2: AorB[] = ['b', 'c'] // <- Errors because 'c' is not part of the union.
```

The type needs to be narrowed at some point from `string` to `AorB`: either when defining the array to only accept `AorB`, using a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to narrow properly from `string` to `AorB`, or the in the receiving function.

Comment: That's not the question. jcalz already answered it properly.

Comment: I'm simply providing an alternative solution because 1) there was no accepted answer and 2) you have yet to respond to what you said is the answer so we have no indication this is closed.